# Understanding spring JDBCTemplate code example

Tags: java, spring

Here is an example from the 14.2.5 section of [SpringJdbc documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html). I didn't get what they tried to say by this code:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class RunAQuery {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from mytable", Integer.class);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select name from mytable", String.class);
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
}
```

Duplication of the setter method for the dataSource object prevents this code even be compiled. What did they actually want to say?

Comment: I think it is a bug in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `setDataSource` method is an error and should not be there. Otherwise this code shows how the `JdbcTemplate` can be used in a DAO. The DB connections encapsulated by the template participate in transactions and you don't have to care about closing DB resources like cursors or statements.